# Remove values from dataframe if a column contains any string value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove rows from my dataframe that contains a string value for a float dtype column. For example if I have an amount field, I want to remove all rows in the dataframe that contains a value of "NA" in the amount field.

So far I've tried the following -

```
to_drop = ['NA']
data = data[~data['gross'].isin(to_drop)]
```

and

```
data = data[data.gross.str != 'NA']
```

I get "an only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas".

What is the correct way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `NA` is missing value (`NaN`) need [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) or [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with specify columns for check `NaN`s:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'gross':[np.nan,3,5],
                     'a':[2,3,4]})

print (data)
   a  gross
0  2    NaN
1  3    3.0
2  4    5.0

data1 = data[data.gross.notnull()]
print (data1)
   a  gross
1  3    3.0
2  4    5.0
```

---

```
data1 = data.dropna(subset=['gross'])
print (data1)
   a  gross
1  3    3.0
2  4    5.0
```

Or if mixed values - numeric with strings first cast all values to `str` or compare numpy array created by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'gross':['NA',3,5,'NA'],
                     'a':[2,3,4,8]})

print (data)
   a gross
0  2    NA
1  3     3
2  4     5
3  8    NA

data2 = data[data.gross.astype(str) != 'NA']
print (data2)
   a gross
1  3     3
2  4     5
```

---

```
data2 = data[data.gross.values != 'NA']
print (data2)
   a gross
1  3     3
2  4     5
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
data['gross'] = data.gross.replace('NA',np.nan)
data = data.dropna()
```

Or

```
data[~data.gross.replace('NA',np.nan).isnull()]
```

Replace string 'NA' with NaN then use dropna axis=1 to drop those rows.